# How can I deploy an Azure App Service on VPC

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cloud, vpc

I have a simple azure web app that I'd like to be accessible only to another azure web app. Is there a way to achieve this very simple thing without having to pay arm and leg for Azure Service Environment

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy your Azure App service on a virtual machine , there is no way to do that. But if you deploy your web application on an Azure VM your requirement can be implemented easily : just using this feature , your web app service can access your web application hosted on virtual machine in Azure VENT and your web application is 100% secure as there is no route to access it for public accesses.

If Azure web app service is necessary for your web application,you can [adding your first web app service outbound IP into IP whitelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) of the web app service that you want to limit accesses by others . For how to find outbound IP of web app service, pls refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips)

However, you know for common Azure app services ,outbound IPs are shared with other common Azure web apps , so this way is available but not so perfect.

[Using managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity) to protect your web app service will be a better and easy way I think: Requests that have passed Azure AD auth will be able to access your web app service.

What's more , in previous link , all ways to protect your web app service have been listed under "Secure app" section , which will be helpful for you too.

Comment: Hi , pls mark me if my suggestions are helpful , if you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know : )